# I'm having trouble with my Drawer navigatio bar not showing up in my main activity

Tags: android, kotlin, binding, navigation, navigation-drawer

i cant get my drawer base to show in my main activity layout.

I'm using kotlin and i have tried even changing add drawerbase as an extension but still wouldnt work. When ever i just change the binding to either ActivityMainBinding or DrawerBaseActivityBinding it just opens one or the other as the activity.

I'm trying to make it where the Drawer opens up in my Main activity when the app opens up as well as opens when going to any other activity i plan to add.

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.cameron.armymaintenance

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.cameron.armymaintenance.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

DrawerBaseActivity.kt

```
package com.cameron.armymaintenance

import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

class DrawerBaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout? = null

    override fun setContentView(view: View?) {
        drawerLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_drawer_base, null) as DrawerLayout
        val container = drawerLayout!!.findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.activityContainer)
        container.addView(view)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_base)
        val toolbar = drawerLayout!!.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolBar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        val navigationView = drawerLayout!!.findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawerLayout,
            toolbar,
            R.string.menu_drawer_open,
            R.string.menu_drawer_open
        )
        drawerLayout!!.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    private fun allocateActivityTitle(titleString: String?) {
        if (supportActionBar != null) {
            supportActionBar!!.title = titleString
        }
    }
}
```

activitydrawerbase.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DrawerBaseActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/content_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/main_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/main_drawer_menu"/>


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

contentlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/Gray"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/White"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/activityContainer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appBarLayout"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Change `setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_base)` in `DrawerBaseActivity` to `super.setContentView(drawerLayout)`.

Comment: i just did it but it still didnt apply the drawer layout inside of the mainactivity

Comment: Oh, right. You forgot to extend `DrawerBaseActivity`, too; i.e., `class MainActivity : DrawerBaseActivity()`.

Comment: i tried that as well but it gives me the error,

```
This type is final, so it cannot be inherited from
```

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is ScrollView but Int was expected
```
both errors in MainActivity.kt

Comment: Change to `open class DrawerBaseActivity : AppCompatActivity()…`. Actually, it could probably be `abstract`, unless you plan to use `DrawerBaseActivity` on its own.

Comment: Man i can't thank you enough, i even tried the open class earlier but didnt have a couple other things correct. it works now. I appreciate it a ton. Thank you.